# Mysql Logic for Absent Date

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having 3 table How to get the absent of all Employee for particular date range using manageriD

1) **lookup** table for dates(Lookuptable for all month)*/
    example

```
╔════════════╗
║    DATE    ║
╠════════════╣
║ 2013-01-01 ║
║ 2013-01-02 ║
║ 2013-01-03 ║
╚════════════╝
```

Second **Employee** Table where i have column such as ( Employee table for all employees with manager id)

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦════════╦══════════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ EMPLOYEEID ║ BRANCHID ║ DEPTID ║ DESIGNID ║ NAME  ║ MANAGERID ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║          1 ║        1 ║     10 ║        5 ║ A     ║        15 ║
║          2 ║        2 ║     10 ║        5 ║ AB    ║        18 ║
║          3 ║        1 ║     10 ║        5 ║ ABC   ║        15 ║
║          5 ║        1 ║     10 ║        5 ║ ABCD  ║        15 ║
║          9 ║        2 ║     10 ║        5 ║ AEFG  ║        16 ║
║         12 ║        1 ║     10 ║        5 ║ AHIJ  ║        15 ║
║          8 ║        1 ║     10 ║        5 ║ AKLMN ║        18 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩════════╩══════════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

Third table is **Login** and out Table(login and logout for all employee )

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ EMPLOYEEID ║ BRANCHID ║    CHECKLOGSDATE    ║ CHECKINTYPE ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║          1 ║        1 ║ 2013-01-01 09:12:15 ║ in          ║
║          1 ║        2 ║ 2013-01-01 19:24:15 ║ out         ║
║          2 ║        1 ║ 2013-01-01 10:20:15 ║ in          ║
║          2 ║        1 ║ 2013-01-01 18:24:15 ║ out         ║
║          3 ║        2 ║ 2013-01-01 09:12:15 ║ in          ║
║          3 ║        1 ║ 2013-01-01 16:24:15 ║ out         ║
║          4 ║        1 ║ 2013-01-01 09:32:15 ║ in          ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83636/1)

Comment: pls specify what is your question ...

Comment: are you storing `employee` attendance in `checkintype` column like `in` means `present` and `out` means `absent`.is it

Comment: can you show what is your desired result?

Comment: i wan to know no absent for set of employee come under managerid    1) I will check whether employee was  present on particular date by checking (from login table) 2)i will check for any holidays like sunday ( dayofweek! =1) and any festivals(from holiday table)3)then i will compare both 1 and 2 with look update table(i have entered all date from 2011-01-01 to 2020-12-31)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your question what are the rules to tell that employee is absent on any given day. If it's just absence of any record (in or out) in the log then you can try

**Updated**

```
SELECT d.date, e.employeeid, e.name
  FROM lookup d CROSS JOIN employee e LEFT JOIN log l 
    ON d.date = DATE(l.Checklogsdate)
   AND e.employeeid = l.employeeid   
 WHERE e.managerid = 15  
   AND d.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-02'
   AND l.employeeid IS NULL
 GROUP BY d.date, e.employeeid, e.name
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83636/38)** demo.

**Original**

```
SELECT e1.date, e1.employeeid, e1.name
  FROM
(
 SELECT d.date, e.employeeid, e.name
   FROM lookup d CROSS JOIN employee e
   WHERE managerid = 15  
     AND d.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-01-02'
) e1 LEFT JOIN
(
 SELECT l.employeeid, DATE(MIN(l.Checklogsdate)) date
   FROM log l JOIN employee e 
     ON l.employeeid = e.employeeid
    AND e.managerid = 15  
  GROUP BY l.employeeid, DATE(l.Checklogsdate)
) l1
    ON e1.date = l1.date
   AND e1.employeeid = l1.employeeid 
 WHERE l1.employeeid IS NULL
 ORDER BY e1.date, e1.employeeid
```

Sample output:

```
|             DATE | EMPLOYEEID | NAME |
----------------------------------------
| January, 01 2013 |          5 | ABCD |
| January, 01 2013 |         12 | AHIJ |
| January, 02 2013 |          1 |    A |
| January, 02 2013 |          3 |  ABC |
| January, 02 2013 |          5 | ABCD |
| January, 02 2013 |         12 | AHIJ |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83636/39)** demo.

Comment: @vishu Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: i wan to know no absent for set of employee come under managerid    1) I will check whether employee was  present on particular date by checking (from login table) 2)i will check for any holidays like sunday ( dayofweek! =1) and any festivals(from holiday table)3)then i will compare both 1 and 2 with look update table(i have entered all date from 2011-01-01 to 2020-12-31)

Comment: @vishu Your original question lacks information about additional tables and desired output to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.Name
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.ManagerId = 15
AND e.Name NOT IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT e.Name
    FROM Log l
    INNER JOIN Employee e ON l.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
    WHERE e.ManagerId = 15
)
```

Here `15` will be replaced by your desired number

[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83636/21)